# Silverlight Mouse Class

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to translate this code into Silverlight. Any suggestions for a replacement for the Mouse class?

```
    private void AssociatedObject_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released && Mouse.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released && Mouse.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released && Mouse.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Released && Mouse.XButton2 == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectAll();
            _alreadyFocused = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to capture the Mouse Events, as described in this SO answer: [How to get the mouse button state in Silverlight outside of button press events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589557/how-to-get-the-mouse-button-state-in-silverlight-outside-of-button-press-events)

Comment: I don't like that solution. The CaptureMouse logic is far too brittle for my taste.

Comment: @Jonathan - Hmm.. I didn't say I like it either :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Silverlight's Mouse support.

All Mouse Support for Silverlight can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189029%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Good Luck.